# gltf-model not working with aframe-extras

Tags: aframe

I need to use aframe-extras to be able to teleport. But if I use aframe-extras gltf-model do not show.

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="assets/lib/aframe-extras.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="assets/lib/aframe.min.js"></script> -->
 </head>
 <body>
   <a-scene>
     <a-assets>
       <a-asset-item id="yoda" src="assets/models/sgp24_yoda_master/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
     </a-assets>

     <a-entity gltf-model="#yoda" position="0 1.25 -5"></a-entity>
   </a-scene>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to import both a-frame and a-frame-extras. One of the script tags is commented out in your snippet. a-frame has to also load first:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="assets/lib/aframe.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/lib/aframe-extras.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a-scene>
     <a-assets>
       <a-asset-item id="yoda" src="assets/models/sgp24_yoda_master/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
     </a-assets>

     <a-entity gltf-model="#yoda" position="0 1.25 -5"></a-entity>
   </a-scene>
 </body>
</html>
```